# Find infinitely many polynomials $f_1(x), f_2(x), . . .$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ such that $f_i (a) = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification

> Let $p$ be a prime. Find infinitely many polynomials $f_1(x), f_2(x), . . .$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$ such that $f_i (a) = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ and all positive integers $i$.

**My attempt:** Since characteristic of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is $p$, a possibility for me would be
$$f_1(x)=px,\; f_2(x)=2px,\; f_3(x)=3px,...$$
In this case if $a\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, we see that for all $i$
$$f_i(a)=npa=n(pa)=n(0)=0$$

Am I right? Is there other possible solution?

Comment: $"pX"$ is the zero polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$. Try $X^{p} - X$ and more generally, $X^{kp} - X$.

Comment: You've found one polynomial, because in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ we have $0=p=2p=3p=...$ and thus in $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, all the polynomials you provided *are* the zero polynomial.

Comment: @Didier what's $k$?

Comment: @Didier This doesn't seem to work: in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, consider $p(x) = x^{2p}-x = x^6-x$. Then $p(2) = 2^6 - 2 = 62 = 2 \neq 0$. My suggestion would be $p_k(x) = (x^p - x)^k$, with $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Gauss Yes! I'm trying with $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and I got to the same. I'll try the  one you say

Comment: @Gauss's idea works, but I think the "canonical" answer is $f_i(x) = x^{p^i}-x$. Each of these $f_i$ leads to a unique [finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Existence_and_uniqueness) that extends $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and has $p^i$ elements. Any finite field is one of these fields for some $p$ and some $i$.

Comment: @Gauss Typo: I meant $X^{kp} - X^k$.

Comment: @Hopmaths $k$ is an integer

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, the polynomial $f_k(X) := X^{kp}-X^k$ works, due to [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). Another polynomial that does the job is the following:
$$
f_k(X) := \prod_{n=0}^{p-1}(X-n)^k.
$$
In my opinion this is the most natural choice, since we force the zeroes of $f_k$ to be exactly the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, with varying multiplicity $k$.